# Distill package.json's dependencies to top-level dependencies only

Tags: npm, create-react-app

After I ejected from `create-react-app`, I was left with a zoo of dependencies inside of `package.json`. Is there a `npm` command or something else that would help me distill the dependencies down and get rid of any package mentions that are only dependencies of some other package. For example, if `package.json` looks like

`package.json`

```
{
  "name": "mypackage",
...
  ],
  "dependencies": {
    "A": "1",
    "B": "1",
    "C": "1",
...
}
```

and both `A` and `B` depend on `C` and I don't care to specify `C`'s version, is there a command to simply remove `C` from `package.json` and thus clean up this file?

Answer (score 0):

`npm prune` should do the job

http://doc.codingdict.com/npm-ref/cli/prune.html

From the docs:

> This command removes "extraneous" packages. If a package name is
> provided, then only packages matching one of the supplied names are
> removed.
>
> Extraneous packages are packages that are not listed on the parent
> package's dependencies list.
>
> If the --production flag is specified or the NODE_ENV environment
> variable is set to production, this command will remove the packages
> specified in your devDependencies. Setting --no-production will negate
> NODE_ENV being set to production.
>
> If the --dry-run flag is used then no changes will actually be made.
>
> If the --json flag is used then the changes npm prune made (or would
> have made with --dry-run) are printed as a JSON object.
>
> In normal operation with package-locks enabled, extraneous modules are
> pruned automatically when modules are installed and you'll only need
> this command with the --production flag.
>
> If you've disabled package-locks then extraneous modules will not be
> removed and it's up to you to run npm prune from time-to-time to
> remove them.

Answer (score 0):

You can delete it manually or use `npm uninstall dependency name` to delete it